# Apply price rule to variants of a configurable product?

Tags: rules, configurable-product

Our apparel store is built with configurable products. We'd like to create a Catalog Price Rule that targets only specific variants of a configurable product. For example, all 'Guys' shirts.

It doesn't appear that this is possible out of the box with Magento unless I'm missing something. Has anyone found a way to do something like this just using Mage configuration?

Originally asked:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224108/apply-price-rule-to-variants-of-a-configurable-product

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is not in the rule conditions itself. It's in the way prices are displayed and calculated by Magento for configurable products. The price of the configurable product is always leading unless you specify different price on the Associated Products tab. If you use a grouped product this would become possible, because they rely more on the simple product. But this is of course a completely different approach and probably not what you want in an Apparel store.

Answer (score 1):

You can create catalog price rules that are triggered by a particular product attribute or by a particular attribute set, but no, out of the box you can't trigger rules against product type itself.

For this particular case it may be as simple as applying a price rule to Guy's shirts category itself - but that will also catch non-configurable products in that category.

To do this more specifically, you could add one or more extra attributes to your products that you use for targeting. So you could create a dropdown attribute called "Price Rule Group" and populate that drop down with a list of tags that make sense for your store, you can then target the catalog price rule against those tags.

One thing to watch out for, when creating the new attribute/attributes remember to set "Use for promo rule conditions" to "Yes" or the attribute won't show in the price rule conditions list.

The disadvantage of this method is that you're creating a new attribute to replicate data that is essentially already there in your case. However the advantage is that you can be more flexible, so if you had a Women's blouse in a different category that was only a simple product - but that you wanted to share the price rule, now you can.

**UPDATE**

This approach doesn't work as hoped for on variant products as not all variant attributes are passed up to the checkout code and I suspect I missed that when I first read the question.

If you have this issue then one work around is to use the variant price to target the rule. As the variant price becomes a cart item attribute it is available to the promotions code.

So this way you can apply a rule based on an attribute of the configurable product, but that then only applies to a variant with a specific cart item price.

Of course this only helps if your variants have different prices!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can solve your request, check [simple configurable product](https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple)

**UPDATE :**

Damodar Bashyal has been released an extension a few days ago, check this as well.

[Magento custom configurable price display](https://github.com/dbashyal/Magento-custom-configurable-price-display)

Comment: Thanks.  Is SCP still considered stable?  Looks like it hasn't been updated in quite awhile.

Comment: Dear Wilson, I can't say anything. The best way is, try on pre-production server then decide yourself!

Comment: @WilsonSheldon "Damodar Bashyal" has been released a new extension for this, check answer!

Comment: Check SCP's  [github](https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple) version. It is more up-to-date. I am not a big fan of this module, as it makes way to many changes, and you end up with quite a few conflicts with other 3rd party modules. But it does work. I have it installed in a site 1 month ago, and have no issues (except for conflicts with SweetTooth)

Comment: Thanks @dedmeet.  We use Sweet Tooth extensively on this site, so perhaps not a good idea for us but I'll give it a go.  Oguz, thanks for the link on Damodar's extension!  Will check it out as well.

Comment: FWIW I'd second @dedmeet's comment - I used to use the SCP extension a lot, it works and does what it says on the tin - however I avoid it now as in the long run it caused too many clashes with other extensions and was increasing the maintenance cost of the sites I'd installed it in. It by necessity makes a lot of changes to some pretty core parts of the system.

Comment: @OğuzÇelikdemir I would NOT recommend SCP. At first it proved to be very helpful especially when clients have numerous pricing variations that are difficult to setup using the out of the box methods. However SCP has caused a wide range of issues down the road for nearly every project which I've used it on. I have since then stopped using this extension on new projects entirely.

Comment: @Meogi what sort of problems came across? Maybe Damodar take care of this issues!

Comment: @OğuzÇelikdemir One issue, is that when trying to setup promotions in Magento, it is no longer possible to target the configurable product as Magento will behave as if it is the simple product in the cart. Another recent issue that was discovered just a week ago... is that it only supports the `special_price` at a global scope for configurable products. If a client has a multi-store setup with configurable products, supplying a `special_price` value on the simple product at a store view scope other than the global scope will not work. There are more issues however I do not have them documented

Comment: @OğuzÇelikdemir I have not used Damodar's extension before. If it supports these issues I mentioned above that would certainly be helpful to know.